# Can I enclose HTML code(link referring to open a child window) inside a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My JS function is like this, it's getting three values passed as parameters from some other JS function in a child window

```
function setValue(a,b,c)
{
selected_a = 1;
other_b = b;
other_c = c;
document.getElementById('load_value').innerHTML =  a.myfunc();
}
```

And now I want to display the load_value selected("a") as an hyperlink which when clicked takes it back to the child window that it got value from.

Now can I include HTML tags into JavaScript to make that hyperlink redirect?

like I want this HTML to be included in a JavaScript

```
<a onclick="window.open('https://url/ Name=','searchA','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=500px,height=450px')" href="#">A</a>
```

Note:The JavaScript is within Perl file.

Answer (score 0):

```
var win = window.open();
win.document.body.innerHTML = '<h1>hello</h1>';
```

Comment: I appreciate it,But i am afraid it doesn't answer my question. I want it to open like a pop-up child window only when clicked and any idea how to add some text before that,like as a separate entity

Comment: you can wrap this into function and call from onclick event. also you can even place this code inside your onclick inline handler.

Comment: your question is how to retrieve some information from child window to main window?

Comment: Nope.I already got that info.It's just that I want to display that info as an Hyperlink which when clicked takes it back to the child window that it got info in the first place and allows user to select any other value there